# Nodejs cluster: why blocking master will block workers too?

Tags: node.js

As you can see, in master(cluster.isMaster) `while loop` is blocking master, but why worker is also blocked?

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const sleep = require('sleep');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });


  // background jobs start
  while(true) {
    console.log(123)
    sleep.sleep(1) // do_background_jobs()
  }
  // background jobs end


} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

Here is logs:

```
Master 45476 is running
Worker 45479 started
Worker 45483 started
Worker 45482 started
Worker 45478 started
```

But `netstat` shows 8000 is closed. of cource `curl` fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limited number of javascript promises is not working if running in infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086784/limited-number-of-javascript-promises-is-not-working-if-running-in-infinite-loop)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question completely. Check out the duplicate question anyway, the reasoning is the same only the details differ. In your case cluster does not work because node uses the master thread as a load balancer to send requests to the cluster workers